# Inverse transformation method

Tags: algorithm

Hi I have implemented the continuous density function `f_m(x)=100(1-x)^{99} , x=[0,1]`, with `F_M(x)=-(1-x)^{100}`.

I simulate random values from this distribution using `X=F^{-1}(u)`, hence `X=1+U^{1/100}` where `U` is `U(0,1)`.

My result is the following

[image: Result]

Now from the formula I am expecting this to peak around 1, not 2. Am I understanding the formula wrong or have I done something wrong in my implementation?

Comment: This looks an awful lot like it belongs on [math.se].

Comment: You should have F(0) = 0 and F(1) = 1 for the cumulative distribution function of a variable in [0,1]. So you want F = 1 - (1-x)^(1/100)

Comment: Thank you beaker, I've forgot the constant when integrating.